# How can I use ptiPython with Flask-Script together?

Tags: flask, ipython, django-extensions, flask-script

In Django, I can use ptiPython instead of IPython after enabling Django-Extensions plugin to enforce Django-Shell. In Flask world, the alternative one of seems to be Flask-Script, I searched around but could not find anything to use ptiPython with Flask-Shell together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flask-Script` support `ipython` and `bpython`. You can create custom `Shell` class

```
from flask.ext.script import Shell
from ptpython.ipython import embed

class PtShell(Shell):
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context()
        embed(user_ns=context)

manager.add_command("shell", PtShell())
```

Comment: This is almost there but ``ptpython.repl.embed`` provides a Python REPL not IPython, so I use `ptpython.ipython.embed`` instead, and change the use to ``embed(user_ns=context)`. Would you mind to have an updating of your answer and I will choose it as the accepted on.